# Java - Passing an array, but it's dropping elements

Tags: java, arrays

```
private static void split(int arr[], int low, int high){
    int[] newArr = arr;
    //Split num of coins into 3 sub arrays
    int mid1 = (int) Math.floor((low+high)/3);
    int mid2 = (int) Math.floor((low+high)/1.5);

    for(int i=0; i<= high; i++){
        System.out.print("newArr:"+newArr[i]+", ");

    }
    System.out.print("mid1:"+mid1+" mid2:"+mid2+"\n");

    int[] a = new int[mid1+1];
    int[] b = new int[mid1+1];
    int[] c = new int[mid1+1];
    int i, j, k;

    for(i=0; i<= mid1; i++){ //1,2,3
        a[i] = arr[i];
        System.out.println("a"+a[i]);
    }
    i=0;
    for(j=mid1+1; j<=mid2; j++){ //4,5,6
        b[i] = arr[j];
        System.out.println("b"+b[i]);
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    for(k=mid2+1; k<=high; k++){ //7,8,9
        c[i] = arr[k];
        System.out.println("c"+c[i]);
        i++;
    }
    System.out.print("a: ");
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        System.out.print(a[i]+", ");
    }
    System.out.print("b: ");
    for(i=0;i<b.length;i++){
        System.out.print(b[i]+", ");
    }
    System.out.print("c: ");
    for(i=0;i<c.length;i++){
        System.out.print(c[i]+", ");
    }
    System.out.println("");

    //Compare
    int sumA=0, sumB=0;
    for(i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        sumA += a[i];
    }
    System.out.println("sumA:"+sumA);
    for(j=0; j<b.length; j++){
        sumB += b[j];
    }
    System.out.println("sumB:"+sumB);

    if(sumA > sumB){
        //check if element is last coin in arr
        if(a.length == 1){
            System.out.print("You've found the coin in a!");
        } else {
            //split a
            System.out.println("split a: ");
            split(a, a[0], a[a.length - 1]);
        }
    }
    else if(sumB > sumA ){
        //check if element is last coin in arr
        if(b.length == 1){
            System.out.print("You've found the coin in b!");
        } else {
            //split b
            System.out.println("split b: ");
            System.out.print("b: ");
            for(i=0;i<b.length;i++){
                System.out.print(b[i]+", ");
            }
            split(b, b[0], b[b.length-1]);
        }
    }
    else{
        //check if element is last coin in arr
        if(c.length == 1){
            System.out.print("You've found the coin in c!");
        } else {
            //split orig last 3
            System.out.println("split c: ");
            split(c, c[0], c[c.length - 1]);
        }
    }

}
```

My original array = int[] arr = {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0};
I am trying to find the value one. Once it goes through the split function, the values 0,1,0 will be in array b, so then it will call split again, but when you check the newArr in split it only has the value 0 in it instead of 0,1,0. Why are my elements disappearing.

P.S there are a lot of print statements, I've been trying to figure out why it's not grabbing all the elements between the first run and the second run, sorry.

Comment: If you included the parameters that you were calling this particular method with, that'd go a long way to helping you get an answer.  That is to say, include your `main` method and any ancillary methods used to call this method.

Comment: What do you do when `mid2 > high` or `mid1 < low`

Comment: Can you include an example we can run which demonstrates this problem and what you expected to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem you have is that `mid1` and `mid2` are broken if low > 0

```
int mid1 = (int) Math.floor((low+high)/3);
int mid2 = (int) Math.floor((low+high)/1.5);
```

If you want mid1 and mid2 to be 1/3 and 2/3 of the difference you need to write it that way

```
int dif = high - low;
int mid1 = low + dif / 3;
int mid2 = high - dif /3;
//or
int mid2 = low + 2 * dif / 3;
```

or you can write it as one liners with

```
int mid1 = (2 * low + high) / 3;
int mid2 = (low + 2 * high) / 3;
```

Also this code

```
int[] a = new int[mid1+1];
int[] b = new int[mid1+1];
int[] c = new int[mid1+1];
```

also assumes that `low == 0` otherwise what you want is

```
int[] a = new int[mid1 - low]; // how many in the first part
int[] b = new int[mid2 - mid1]; // how many in the second part
int[] c = new int[high - mid2]; // how many in the third part
```

Finally this line makes no sense

```
split(a, a[0], a[a.length - 1]);
```

If `a` contains `[100, 200, 300]` you wouldn't split on `100` to `300`.  What you probably meant was

```
split(a, 0, a.length);
```

which you will note is actually

```
split(arr, low, mid1);
```

meaning you don't need to take a copy of the array at any point.

Comment: Thank you!
low is supposed to be 0 always. I didn't realize I was taking the element of the array, I do that a lot :/.. It runs now after changing a[0] and a[a.length-1] to 0 and a.length-1 haha

Comment: @Felicia in that case you can remove low and simplify the code.